# How to Set Digit must be 10 digit in react native in InputText field

Tags: react-native, validation

I am new to react native. Please tell Me is it possible to set like this =  ten digit must in InputText field in react native
for example Mobile Number must be 10 digit Not more that 10 digit are allowed And not less 10 digit are allowed. Please tell me How can set that

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can achieve this depending on what you prefer.

The first way is to run and changeHandler function on <Text onChangeText={(value) => onChangeHandler(value)} /> and make a check inside the function like this- if (value.length !==10) return or you can show an Alert displaying a message - The mobile number must be 10 digit.

The other way is by using any validation library like simple-react-validation is one which has on option to set the size of input element.

Comment: Can I use it in react native